# Exception while running the simple sh script

Tags: scripts, sh

Below is the simple script, while running the script i am getting the exception like line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file. please help.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
a=10
b=20
if [ 10 == 20 ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

Comment: Useful: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 2):

change `==` to `-eq`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
a=10
b=20
if [ 10 -eq 20 ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

BTW: You have set the variables a and b, but you are not using them. I suppose you intended:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
a=10
b=20
if [ $a -eq $b ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

See `man test` for what the expression in the `[ ]` looks like. `=` is for string comparisons, `-eq`, `-gt`, etc. are for integer comparisons.

Comment: Another BTW: if you replace `/bin/sh` by `/bin/bash` your script is working.

Answer (score 2):

First, I believe `[ 10 == 20 ]` is a typo and it should be `[ "$a" == "$b" ]`. Second [@dsstorefile1](https://askubuntu.com/users/799387/dsstorefile1) is right *In POSIX sh, == is not supported.*

If you use `shellcheck` you can find this out yourself:

```bsh
$ shellcheck script.sh 

In script.sh line 4:
if [ "$a" == "$b" ]
          ^-- SC2039: In POSIX sh, == is not supported.
```

Here is a bit advanced version of your script that could handle the first two positional parameters:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
a="$1"
b="$2"
if [ "$a" = "$b" ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

Then you can use it in this way:

```bsh
$ ./script.sh 10 20
a is not equal to b

$ ./script.sh 10 10
a is equal to b
```

Comment: ./duke.sh 10 20
./duke.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./duke.sh: line 9: `fi'

Comment: there is no statement after fi statement.

Comment: Please respond any one.

Comment: @AbhishekGowlikar likely there is something wrong with how you are entering / running the script - such as Windows line endings or other non-printing characters

Comment: @AbhishekGowlikar, please install `shellcheck`: `sudo apt install shellcheck` and check your script ... probably some quote mark or any other symbol is missing.

Comment: @AbhishekGowlikar, you could thanks also by up-vote and (or) accept of the useful answers :-) Btw, Muclux is perfectly right  in your case is much better to use the [integer comparison operators](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html).